# Upload zip & unzip to multiple image field

Tags: media, files

I am using drupal 7 and I want to upload a zip file and automatically extract it into multiple image fields on a node. The zip file contains images. Is there a easy way to do this? cause I'm not a programmer

Comment: Do you have a plan making sure post_max_size and upload_max_filesize versus the size of the zipped files isn't going to be a problem?

Comment: all my zip files are under 100mb so it shouldn't be a problem on my vps

Comment: Is there some reason you can't/won't go the more common way of uploading multiple image files like Rupesh is suggesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [imagefield zip](https://drupal.org/project/imagefield_zip) module. It suits only for drupal 6, but related issues has [two forks](https://drupal.org/node/945502) for drupal 7.

If none of that doesnt suits your needs, you can do it with little trick:

- Create second file field for handle zip file upload;
- Take a look at [unzip](http://drupalcode.org/project/imagefield_zip.git/blob/HEAD:/imagefield_zip.module#l260) function in imagefield zip module;
- Implements something similar in `hook_node_save()`.

If you have module creation skill you can give your solition back to comunity ;)

Comment: I'm not really a programmer so I wouldn't know how to use those functions :(

Comment: pay some kind of money to somebody =)

Answer (score 2):

I think your main goal is upload multiple image on a single upload and this goal you can achive via a module name 'Multiupload Imagefield Widget' https://drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget.

This module provide a widget to select multiple images . For more info go through the module instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7 solution for this issue 
[Pack & Upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/pack_upload).

Got to this post while searching for a solution.